# Excel copy sheet following active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm wanting to copy a sheet using VBA as a new sheet following the sheet being copied

I'm using this code now and it works but puts the copied sheet at the end of the list of sheets

```
Dim x As Integer

x = InputBox("Enter number of times to copy sheet, puts copies at end of sheet list")
For numtimes = 1 To x
  'Loop by using x as the index number to make x number copies.
  ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy _
      After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

Next
```

Lets say the list of sheets is - sheet (1), Sheet (2), Sheet (3), Sheet (4)
if i run the code on Sheet (2) i want the new copy to be in between Sheet (2) and Sheet (3), Is this passable?

Also if i cancel the popup box that asks for the number of sheet copies it gets in error is there a way to keep that from happening?

Comment: Just do `After:=Sheets(Sheets(2))`, no?  Or actually, if you're running this on multiple sheets (and have no variables), `After:=Sheets(Activesheet.index)` should work.

Comment: the After:=Sheets(Activesheet.index) worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the activesheet's index:  `After:=Sheets(Activesheet.Index)`.

Not sure if you know much VBA, but as the name implies, whatever your currently active sheet is, that index will be used.  Without knowing more of your code, it will work for the specific instance you asked about here. BUT if you have multiple worksheets (which you do), you'll probably instead want to set a variable for the worksheet you're working in, then use that in the `Sheets()` part...i.e.

```
Sub t()
Dim x As Integer
Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet

myWorksheet = Sheets("Data Sheet")
x = InputBox("Enter number of times to copy sheet, puts copies at end of sheet list")
For numtimes = 1 To x
  'Loop by using x as the index number to make x number copies.
  myWorksheet.Copy _
      After:=Sheets(myWorksheet.Index)
Next
End Sub
```

Now, this just uses a single worksheet. You'd need to add a little logic to loop through all, but that shouldn't be too hard for you to find out how to do. If you would like any more help, just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

> Also if i cancel the popup box that asks for the number of sheet copies it gets in error is there a way to keep that from happening?

Change type of `x` to Variant. If you click Cancel on input box, empty string is returned which is inappropriate for `Integer`.